# how to import csv in woocommerce with multiple currencies in it

Tags: woocommerce, price

I have a csv that has some products in different currencies (usd and mxn). I'm thinking about adding a custom attribute and modify the price based on that attribute, in order to show only in mxn.

Are there any recommendations or alternatives for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that creating an "Exchange Rate" attribute and a "Common Currency" attribute related to the previous one will do the job.
PD: Since you are using a CSV, please check the decimal separator before creating it.
I hope this guides you,
Regards,